# How to load directive in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Based on this example [throbberDirective](http://codepen.io/apuchkov/pen/lwkdq), How to inject custom directive to the controller, so that you can call the functions show() hide()? I can't get rid of the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: inputThrobberProvider <- inputThrobber <- landingCtrl
```

Example code:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'templates']);

app.directive('inputThrobber', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      controller: function($scope, $element) {
        var inputThrobberCtrl = {
          show: function() {
            $element.addClass('throbbing');
          },
          hide: function() {
            $element.removeClass('throbbing');
          }
        };

        return inputThrobberCtrl;
      }
    };
  }])
  .controller('landingCtrl', ['$scope', 'geolocation', 'inputThrobber', function($scope, geolocation, inputThrobber) {

    // inputThrobber.show()
    geolocation.getAddress().then(function(address) {
        $scope.address = address;
      }).catch(function(err) {
        $scope.error = error;
        $scope.address = '';
      })
      .finally(function() {
        // $inputThrobber.hide()
      });

  }]);
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it once it's there?

Comment: Trying to inject a directive into a controller doesn't make sense. Directives are for doing DOM manipulation. Controllers should not know about the DOM.

Comment: I'm trying to add [inputThrobber](http://codepen.io/apuchkov/pen/lwkdq) directive directly in controller, so when my resources are resolving then I'll show loading spinner.

Comment: @luzny, it makes no sense to load a directive in the controller, including `inputThrobber`

Comment: @luzny What you want to do is "communicate" between the controller and the directive. There are various ways to do that: using $scopes, events, services/factories, etc. Or for a loading spinner you might look at utilizing Angular's `$httpInterceptor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using that dispatches an event to show/hide the spinner:

```
app.directive('inputThrobber', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      controller: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.$on('startThrobbing', function() {
          $element.addClass('throbbing');
        });
        $scope.$on('stopThrobbing', function() {
          $element.removeClass('throbbing');
        });
      }
    };
  }])

.controller('landingCtrl', ['$scope', 'geolocation', function($scope, geolocation) {
    $scope.$broadcast('startThrobbing');
    geolocation.getAddress().then(function(address) {
        $scope.address = address;
      }).catch(function(err) {
        $scope.error = error;
        $scope.address = '';
      })
      .finally(function() {
        $scope.$broadcast('stopThrobbing');
      });
}]);
```

Comment: it doesn't work unless first broadcast is fired with delay: `$timeout(function() {$scope.$broadcast('startThrobbing');});`, I couldn't find better solution, maybe do you have suggestions?

Comment: @luzny It sounds like the controller gets created and broadcasts the event before the directive is up and running. The timeout is one solution. If you feel like that is a hack, you might consider one of the other means of communicating between controller and directive: using scopes. The directive needs to be on a the same scope or a child scope of the controller. Then set a boolean variable (`$scope.loading = true;`) to trigger the directive. Each means of communication has its pros/cons.

Comment: The ultimate solution would use an [$httpInterceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) to detect when a server request is made/ends. Then you could show the loading indicator on a global basis, and not just this one view. I've seen a bunch of projects on Github that already do this sort of thing.